# Painting new panel on top of another one

Tags: java, jpanel, paint, layer

I have a program where the base panel is just drawing the background (trees, water, etc), and i have a player and other objects moving around the screen. I don't want to call repaint() on the whole thing because it slows me down because it repaints the whole thing. When I try to add a new panel on top that will be repainted a lot and handle moving objects, nothing happens in my code. This is what I have in the constructor for the first

```
public GamePanel()
{ //some code
   top = TopPanel();
   top.setSize(this.getSize());
   add(top);
 //some more code
}
```

and then in the class for the toppanel

```
public TopPanel()
    {

    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        i.drawItem(//);
        player.draw(//fields);
    }
```

And no matter what I do, I can't get anything to show up on the panel when i run it.

Comment: what layout manager are you using, a null layout? if so you need to set the location and size of the TopPanel.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: I've tried that, the only thing that kind of worked was overriding paintChildren, but that only made things slower.

Answer (score 2):

My general approach when rendering a complex but static 'background' with other things painted on top is to draw the background to a `BufferedImage` and simply redraw the image before painting the dynamic parts.

Comment: thanks, that worked like a charm, I have no idea why I didn't think of it before.